# Opening mobile file explorer using cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile

I am working in angular js. I have to upload files from mobile file explorer. input type="file" is not supported for android 4.4+. So i have put a simple text for now , on click of which i want to upload file and save it in a variable as
***metric.output.push(This.target.files[0]);*** 
I am using ngCordova.js library. I am not able to open file exploreer and save file.
Can anyone help me out?